# How to clone BLE device (configurations,charcterstics etc)and share it with other

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, clone, emulation

I am working on an app that gets data from the BLE device, I am able to code to get the app to connect with the BLE device. But further characteristics read is an issue as I don't physically have the device

i came across an app named **[nRF Connect for Mobile](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=no.nordicsemi.android.mcp&hl=en_IN)** . It has the functionality to clone BLE if paired. the video for a BLE clone is shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mun9-Nrp09U&feature=youtu.be) but export and import is not avaible

Is there any way I can get the BLE cloned say some configuration file, which then imported in certain app create then same BLE device .i can use to read all the characteristics and other properties

Comment: The video you posted doesn't seem to be doing anything fancy. It looks like it just records the advertising data and then advertises with that, and discovers the services and characteristics, and then advertises with those. It's not a trivial amount of work (and I think a lot more code than makes sense for StackOverflow, particularly adding the configuration features you're describing), but it's not clear what the question is. "How" looks like standard CoreBluetooth discovery (scanForPeripherals, followed by discoverServices, followed by discoverCharacteristics followed by read).

Comment: With Android, you can get closer to a full "clone" than you can with iOS; some low-level queries are impossible in iOS, and you have more limitations in how you advertise, so it might be easier to write this for Android instead. But the basic approach looks the same.

Comment: @RobNapier you are correct that the video is not doing anything fancy. But posted to show that is their anyway. Somebody can clone a BLE device with some application and share say a file may some .abc extension and then imported into the same application simlate the same BLE device . as i am writng any app that reads from BLE device  and  able to read .but sure about all the services that device provides.

Comment: @RobNapier apologies if it doesn't make sense.since there are a number of solution that can create a virtual BLE device for the test but not a singe that helps to clone and share it with others.My query is not much related to code.

Comment: Maybe you can take something like https://github.com/Pluto-Y/Swift-LightBlue and just add export and import.

Comment: OK, I see the question. You're asking for an existing tool or app; that's off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is why I think there was some confusion. Stack Overflow answers programming questions, and you can certainly write this app, but I don't know of something on the shelf that does it.

Comment: @RobNapier  although Question is off-topic, this will help a lot to developers working on BLE,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question and your video correctly, you would like to copy the advertisement data of a BLE peripheral and use it to advertise on an iOS device yourself.

Maybe [`CBPeripheralManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager) can help you do that.
You can call [`startAdvertising([String:Any]?)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbperipheralmanager/1393252-startadvertising) and advertise a BLE peripheral.
But iOS limits on a system level which keys you can advertise.
From a short look in the documentation, it seems only the keys

1. `CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey`
2. `CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey`

are supported.

But if you'd want to include more information about your peripheral, you could still create an own `CBMutableService` "deviceInfo" and send information within a characteristic after having established a connection.

Comment: I am aware of `CBPeripheralManager` but I don't have the BLE  device physically with me to fetch the device data .but in case anyway to clone the BLE device for the purpose of simulation  , that i need to know

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just connect to the device in for example nRF Connect, write down the services, characteristics and descriptors you see (usually isn't *that* many). Then just set up a local GATT server with the same content.

Comment: I don't have the BLE device physically with me. question is simply that if any app that clone the BLE device (Advertisement data , services  UUID, etc )  and then can share and imported into the same app and then simulate the same BLE device .that I can use to get  all data.